# Setting one callback for multiple events in jquery-UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

This might be a silly question to ask if I am missing a key point. I want to create a draggable which is resizable too. I don't know what is the proper way to do it but I did something like this:

```
$('#MYID').resizable();
$('#MYID').draggable();
```

Now I want to move it to some position and when everything is finalized save the position using: `$('#MYID').ui-position`. I am not sure how to implement the callback function in this case. If I use callback in like this:

```
$('#MYID').resizable();
$('#MYID').draggable()(Function()({....callback code for ui-position})
```

This is okay if the user does not resize the draggable after placing it in one position but what if he does?

How can I set one callback happening after the completion of two events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have them both set a flag, and then use a conditional that if both flags are set call the completion function

```
var flagA = 0;
var flagB = 0;
...
completeResize:
 flagA = 1;
 if(flagA && flagB)completionFunction();
...
completeDraggable:
 flagB = 1;
 if(flagA && flagB)completionFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an interesting plugin called [eventstack](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/eventstack). It lets you bind events to either the top or the bottom of the event queue. I don't know how general your problem is, or whether you're looking to reverse or to arbitrarily order events in your stack, but the plugin may simplify your task.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I am not sure it is relevant. Simply set a flag to true on each event completion and in the callback test if this flag is set to true and then proceed. Try to stay away from plugins where you can!

Answer (score 0):

Because jQuery objects are chainable, to make you element both draggable and resizable, you can do this:

```
$('#MYID').resizable().draggable();
```

Then, it doesn't really matter if you call the same event handler twice because you only want to save the final position. So, you can just register both events like this:

```
$('#MYID').on('resizestop dragstop', function(event, ui) { 
                                        alert(ui.offset);  /* or whatever */
                                    }
```